# How do I find the amount of entry's over a interval? MySQL and Grafana

Tags: grafana

I want to calculate the amount of data being used by my machines. They are reporting the sum of their data every minute. I have put a quarry together that gives me the difference between the latest entry and a lag of about 24h but as the amount of system will change this rate will change.

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  machine_id,
  ABS ( utilisation - LAG(utilisation,2160) OVER ( PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY time)) as DataUsed
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = 'network'
ORDER BY time
```

I need to replace 2160 with the count of entries over $__interval which is defined by the grafana dashboard

```
SELECT
  $__unixEpochGroupAlias(time,$__interval),
  count(utilisation) AS "count"
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = 'network'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY $__unixEpochGroup(time,$__interval)
```

Im a little lost as the above query does not actually give me the number of entries over the time span as I thought it would.

This is how the data is stored

[DataView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8KeQ.png)

Query A

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  machine_id,
  utilisation - LAG(utilisation,88) OVER ( PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY time) as DataUsed
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = 'network'
ORDER BY time
```

Query B

```
SELECT
  machine_id,
  count(utilisation) AS N
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = "network"
GROUP BY machine_id
```

[image]

Comment: how do I nest query B in A.  the output of B is N which is where 89 goes in the count.